# Why show unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python

my code is the next

```
data_temp = [(atributos[0],atributos[1],atributos[2],atributos[3],atributos[4],atributos[5],atributos[6],atributos[7],atributos[8],atributos[9],atributos[10],atributos[11],atributos[12],atributos[13])]


lectura = csv.reader(open("Dataset.csv","r"))
dis = [] #creamos una lista vacia para almacenar las distancias de cada instancia
for index,row in enumerate(lectura):
dato2 = [float(row[0]), float(row[1]),float(row[2]), float(row[3]),float(row[4]),float(row[5]),float(row[6]),float(row[7]),float(row[8]),int(row[9]),int(row[10]),int(row[11]),int(row[12]),int(row[13])]
d = calcular_distancia(data_temp,dato2)
```

and the error is

```
def calcular_distancia(d1,d2):
distancia = ((d1[0]-d2[0])**2+(d1[1]-d2[1])**2+(d1[2]-d2[2])**2+(d1[3]-d2[3])**2+(d1[4]-d2[4])**2+(d1[5]-d2[5])**2+(d1[6]-d2[6])**2+(d1[7]-d2[7])**2+(d1[8]-d2[8])**2+(d1[9]-d2[9])**2+(d1[10]-d2[10])**2+(d1[11]-d2[11])**2+(d1[12]-d2[12])**2+(d1[13]-d2[13])**2)
return math.sqrt(distancia)
```

and finish the program with

```
distancia = ((d1[0]-d2[0])**2+(d1[1]-d2[1])**2+(d1[2]-d2[2])**2+(d1[3]-d2[3])**2+(d1[4]-d2[4])**2+(d1[5]-d2[5])**2+(d1[6]-d2[6])**2+(d1[7]-d2[7])**2+(d1[8]-d2[8])**2+(d1[9]-d2[9])**2+(d1[10]-d2[10])**2+(d1[11]-d2[11])**2+(d1[12]-d2[12])**2+(d1[13]-d2[13])**2)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:c]? Also, we need a [MCVE].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: What happens if my vector has 15 entries?

Comment: @en_Knight, check my solution. I made the adjustment for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your d1 and d2 variables are not a list of floats. Instead, they're a list of tuples. Somewhere in your code that you haven't shown, d1[i] and d2[i] are assigned tuple values.

Also, to calculate your distances, I would do the following: If you have 2 lists of floats.
map the index to the difference of the corresponding index in d1 and d2 squared. Then sum and sqrt the squared difference list. It'll help reduce your long summation.

```
return math.sqrt(sum( list(map(lambda i: (d1[i] - d2[i])**2, range(len(d1))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a list of tuples into your `calcular_distancia` function as the first argument `d1`. You may have expected `data_temp` to be a list of `float` values, but it is actually a list of (1) 14-element tuple, as shown below:

```
>>> data_temp = [(atributos[0],atributos[1],atributos[2],atributos[3],atributos[4],atributos[5],atributos[6],atributos[7],atributos[8],atributos[9],atributos[10],atributos[11],atributos[12],atributos[13])]
>>> type(data_temp)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(data_temp[0])
<type 'tuple'>
>>> len(data_temp)
1
>>> len(data_temp[0])
14
```

The root issue, I suspect, is that you used both the square brackets `[]` and parentheses `()` when defining `data_temp`. If you remove the `()` in the definition of `data_temp`, you should get the results you expect.